# Laravel composer autoload file error

Tags: laravel, composer-php

[pid 24634] [client 192.168.1.254:53250] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/bab_dev/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/bab_dev/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Laravel error coming i have run composer command successfully still shows this error in error log file please guide

Comment: try to run composer update or composer install

Comment: already did still same issue persists

Comment: hi can you check this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/composer-install-failing-vendor-folder-missing

Answer (score 1):

run command

```
composer install
```

and then, run command

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: now it gives 500 HTTP_ERROR no error log genrating in error_log file